# Copy Cassandra database to test host

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I want to copy a Cassandra database to my Ubuntu 12.04 system (not going to be used for production, just for my testing - and yes, I'm completely new to Cassandra) so that I can look at the database and not have to worry about messing things up. What's the easiest way to copy a complete Cassandra database to another host?

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your setup. Usually if the source Cluster consists of multiple nodes, you will have to create a snapshot of each node at the same time, then copy the snapshot from /var/lib/cassandra/data///snapshots/ of all nodes over to the single destination host. That way you ensure you didn't miss anything.

My preferred way of doing this is by automation. If your test environment has the same number of nodes as production then you can use tools like Priam (https://github.com/Netflix/Priam) to automate restore to your test cluster from a production backup. I use this method to automatically refresh our staging environment with production snapshot from the night before every day.

Perhaps the first method can be automated too.

Comment: OK, so I'm probably just not particularly bright, but...What I have done here, so far, is to create snapshots of all the column families in the key space that I want to copy. I then copied them to my local node, but Cassandra isn't see them. I assume that there is some additional step I need to take to make Cassandra aware of the new key space that I don't know about.

My environment is a single node "cluster" running Cassandra with a single keyspace (other than system) that I would like to copy to my local node. What do I need to do to make Cassandra aware of the new key space?

Comment: Have you also copied system's keyspace? Try this instead on your test machine: delete the system's keyspace by shutting down Cassandra and then removing the system keyspace files. Then start cassandra. Go to cassandra-cli or cqlsh, whichever you are familiar with, and re-execute the create schema commands that were used to create the original cluster. Then cassandra comes to know about the schema. Restart and it should look your schema files.

Comment: I kept having problems using the Ubuntu apt-get version, it is 1.1.12 and the cluster is using 1.2.10, so I finally just downloaded 1.2.10 from Apache, installed it into a local directory under my home directory, followed your instructions, i.e. I copied the snapshots to the local data directory under the keyspace name, shutdown cassandra, removed data/system, restarted cassandra and used cassandra-cli < keyspace.schema, restarted cassandra and it all seems to be working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I use Ubuntu as well. Agree the packages are old and not well maintained. You can use DataStax repository. I personally maintain my own version. You can git clone cassandra repository on a machine that has ant installed. Then just run this command and it will build the debian packages for you: dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -d. Just note that you should checkout the git tag referencing the version you want.